# NoSql Design, AWS (DynamoDB) or Azure(DocumentDB)?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am planning on moving our people/address/telephone database from Sql Server into a NoSQL db for scalability reasons.

We currently have all our infrastructure on AWS and Azure and we are planning on keeping it that way. Hence, I started researching the tools provided by both AWS and Azure but I am in doubt and wish I could get some help.

Here's the basic structure of our tables:

**Person**
ID,
Name,
Surname,
DOB,
Job,
EmailAddress,
Nationality,
CityOfBirth,
Etc...

**Address**
PersonId,
Street,
Number,
ZipCode,
City,
etc...

**Telephone**
PersonId,
Number,
AreaCode,
Carrier,
etc...

---

**Queries:**
The main query that we perform is to obtain people based on columns from Person (DOB, Job, etc), Address (ZipCode Range, State, City, etc) and Telefone (Carrier, Telefone Type, etc) tables. We filter need to select millions of records on a daily basis to generate the data to be processed by our app.

My typical query returns the following columns:

Person Table: ID, Name, Surname, DOB, Job, EmailAddress, Nationality, CityOfBirth

Address Table: Street, Number, ZipCode, City, State

Telephone Table (5 phone numbers per person): Number, AreaCode, Carrier

Queries usually return from 5k~15k records, and we need to obtain the full resultset.

We also perform updates on the telephone data on a weekly basis, adding/removing/updating phone numbers. We do it on the weekend to avoid impacting performance on the production application.

I understand that I would have to denormalize this structure to facilitate querying and improve read performance. So I starting assessing both cloud providers for the possible solutions:

**AWS DynamoDB**
From what I could understand I cannot implement queries on multiple attributes and there is a limit on Indexes that can be created. I couldn't think of a way to model the data to allow for fast querying using the filters mentioned.

It seems to me that I could perform query on the most important fields and then apply filtering on the rest. I am not sure if it would be optimal, given that I have 50 million + records.

Or is there another AWS Service that could assist me on achieving the desired behavior?

**Azure DocumentDB**
Since it stores JSON objects which are indexed by all attributes I could be the way to go. I is supposed to be less performant than KEY/Value Tables and I am not aware of the actual performance when querying for millions of records on a daily basis.

Again, I am not sure if is there another service that could prive better results on Azure.

**Conclusion:**
I would like to get some insight that could lead me into the right direction. I've seem some questions regarding Elasticsearch and etc that could assist in this, but I am not sure if it would give the performance I was hoping for and if it is actually its purpose.

**Objective**
What is driving us to look for alternatives is to take advantage of cloud's flexibility. Nowadays we keep a large SQL Server 24/7 to host this core data of our application. We are hoping to improve query performance and reduce server costs.

Not sure what if NoSQL is the way to go, or remaining on SQL Server with changes on the data structure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of scalability? Read, write, storage? Maybe you really want a directory service like openldap? :)

Comment: Since the amount of persons is quite limited, SQL Server with proper indices should be able to fit your requirements. Same for Document DB. Describe your queries in more details and what problems you get with SQL.

Comment: I've updated the question hoping to clear some of your doubts. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: To provide answer, need the following information
-Rough size of an item and total size of your data
-Rate of growth of your data
-Items in a average query (Also the max value)
Also upon query, does your operation requires the entire dataset or can it operate on page by page?

Comment: @Ashan The database has 1,2TB. The db is not growing that fast, 100MB/Month. Regarding the Query, I've updated the question with that info. Thanks!